# How to extract a few levels from a large statistical result in R?

Tags: r, extract

I am not sure if I have used the correct words in the question title, so please let me explain. Lets say, I have a dataset with three factors: species, life, and exposure and one response variable: mean_v. In total there are 108 levels. When I apply 3-way ANOVA followed by Tukey's post-hoc test, it generates a very large number of statistical comparisons.

```
life <- rep(c("5d", "15d", "45d"), 2, each = 18)
species <- rep(c("SP1", "SP2"), each = 54)
exposure <- rep(c("c1", "c2", "c3"), 6, each = 6)
mean_v <- runif(108, 4, 80)
data1 <- data.frame(species, life, exposure, mean_v)
model1 <- aov(mean_v~species*life*exposure, data1)
tukey <- TukeyHSD(model1)
tukey
```

However, I am only interested in few, for example comparison between SP2:5d:c3 - SP1:5d:c3. Is there a way to extract specific comparisons from the whole analysis?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select `species:life:exposure` list inside `tukey` and after that select only the comparison needed, like this:

```
tukey$`species:life:exposure`[rownames(tukey$`species:life:exposure`)=="SP2:5d:c3-SP1:5d:c3",]
      diff        lwr        upr      p adj 
 -2.123986 -47.461693  43.213722   1.000000
```